# How to setup dynamic database to roles on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The point is; my client app creates dynamic mongo databases. Because of secure policy I have to secure all of them before to start.

So I have already this user configuration:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "myUser",
  pwd: "myUser",
  roles: [ 
    { role: "dbOwner", db: "dbname" }
  ]
})
```

What should I do if I add a new database through my client app? Later I will need to add permissions dynamically like:

```
{ role: "readWrite", db: "database_00x" }
```

Are there any way for using regular expressions or something?

Thanks!